# Why Spring is highlighting tight coupling, though it can be overcome by programatically?

Tags: java, spring

So my doubt may be because of am lacking some concepts. But why spring is highlighting tight coupling is one of the problem it tries to resolve?
For example **Red Color and Blue color implements Color interface**
so the service class is hard coded that is what they mean by tight coupling
Why cant we use ***conditionals*** to generate corresponding implementations to tackle this problem?

```
if(color=red)
  return new Red()
else
  return new Blue()
```

why this is not a solution for tight coupling?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  What is "highlighting" the problem?  How is it highlighting it?  It is a tool? And IDE?

Comment: *"why this is not a solution for tight coupling?"* - Because it is (IMO) an *example* of tight coupling.  You are still hard-wiring the use of two specific classes (`Red` and `Blue`) into that code.  That is a form of tight coupling.  It is hard to say whether it is harmful in an artificial example like this one.  But in other circumstances it >can< be.

Comment: @StephenC thanks for clarifying doubt on Tight coupling. So it is like whenever there is an instance of another class is instantiated it is tightly coupled right?

Comment: No.  The issue is that you are hard-wiring specific >classes< into the code.  Loose coupling would be if the instances of those classes were (for example) created using factory objects, or if they were injected using Dependency Injection.  So that (for example) use different versions of the `Red` class : `Crimson`, `Scarlet`, `Cerise` and so on.

Comment: I suggest you read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming) for some background on what Coupling means